# Gauss-Jordan Elimination

Tags: c++, gaussian

I have to design an algorithm as an extension of forward elimination that does Gauss Jordan Eliminations on a matrix.  My program is executing and creating the diagonal of numbers, but they are not all 1s.  It also wont access the first row and first column to change them to 0s.  And the final column, the one where the answer should be, doesn't change.  Any ideas what I could do to get closer to the solution?

```
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double BetterForwardElimination(double A[8][9])
{

//Implements Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting
//Input: Matrix A[1..n,1..n] and column-vector b[1..n]
//Output: An equivalent upper-triangular matrix in place ofAand the
//corresponding right-hand side values in place of the (n+1)st column

    //size of array
    int n = 8;
    //int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);

for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
{
    int pivotrow = i;
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (A[j][i] > A[pivotrow][i])
        {
            pivotrow = j;
        }
    }

    for (int k=i; k<n-1; k++)
    {
        swap(A[i][k], A[pivotrow][k]);
    }

    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
        //int temp = A[j][i]/A[i][i];
        for (int k = i; k<n; k++)
        {
            A[j][k] = A[j][k] - A[i][k]*(A[j][i]/A[i][i]);
        }
        A[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

return A[n][n];
}
```

My output is something like this:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   
1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   
11  0   0   0   5   0   0   0   20  
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   34  
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   -51 
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1  -6
```

Expected output should be:

```
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   5   
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   7   
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   -7  
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   -5  
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   -3  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   -2
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @askewchan just edited it into the first post

Answer (score 1):

Based on the algorithm, `A[j][i] > A[pivotrow][i]` should be `|A[j][i]| > |A[pivotrow][i`]|, both of them are absolute values. And where is your swap function? I don't think C++ has its own `swap(int[][] a, int[][]b)`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his use of `std::swap` -- the arguments are array elements, not entire arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a [QMatrix](https://moldovean@bitbucket.org/moldovean/qmatrix.git%20%22QMatrix) class. It uses the built in vector > container.

You can use it as follows:

```
#include "QMatrix.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
QMatrix<double> A(3,3,true);
QMatrix<double> Result = A.inverse()*A; //should give the idendity matrix

std::cout<<A.inverse()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<Result<<std::endl; // for checking
return 0;
}
```

If you would like to see how it works, the inverse function is implemented as follows:

The class has the following fields:

```
template<class T> class QMatrix{
public:
int rows, cols;
std::vector<std::vector<T> > A;
```

the inverse() function:

```
template<class T> 
QMatrix<T> QMatrix<T>:: inverse(){
Identity<T> Id(rows); //the Identity Matrix as a subclass of QMatrix.
QMatrix<T> Result = *this; // making a copy and transforming it to the Identity matrix
T epsilon = 0.000001;
for(int i=0;i<rows;++i){
    //check if Result(i,i)==0, if true, switch the row with another

    for(int j=i;j<rows;++j){
        if(std::abs(Result(j,j))<epsilon) { //uses Overloading()(int int) to extract element from Result Matrix
            Result.replace_rows(i,j+1); //switches rows i with j+1
        }
        else break;
    }
    // main part, making a triangular matrix
    Id(i)=Id(i)*(1.0/Result(i,i));
    Result(i)=Result(i)*(1.0/Result(i,i));  // Using overloading ()(int) to get a row form the matrix
    for(int j=i+1;j<rows;++j){
        T temp = Result(j,i);
        Result(j) = Result(j) - Result(i)*temp;
        Id(j) = Id(j) - Id(i)*temp; //doing the same operations to the identity matrix
        Result(j,i)=0; //not necessary, but looks nicer than 10^-15
    }
}

// solving a triangular matrix 
for(int i=rows-1;i>0;--i){
    for(int j=i-1;j>=0;--j){
        T temp = Result(j,i);
        Id(j) = Id(j) - temp*Id(i);
        Result(j)=Result(j)-temp*Result(i);
    }
}

return Id;
}
```

It works fine... but there should be ways to improve its speed without compromising flexibility.